# Audio streaming using Wowza and HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, wowza

I've uploaded a mp3 file to Wowza and now I'm trying to play it using the HTML5 audio tag. However, it just doesn't work.

Here's how my HTML code looks like:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://example.com/vods3/_definst_/mp3:amazons3/videosciatech/testemp3/Kalimba.mp3/playlist.m3u8" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Chrome: play button is disabled
Firefox: player disappears
IE: player displays "Invalid source" error message

Am I doing it wrong? What's the proper way of doing this?

Edit: I just found out it works in Safari for iPad! So now my question would be: how to make it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking to a playlist... for HLS usage.  Unfortunately, not many browsers support HLS.

Link to the MP3 file itself.

Comment: How can I do that? Removing "/playlist.m3u8" from the end of the URL doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @vitorsdcs I don't know what your URL is for your MP3 file, sorry.  Depending on how the HLS is set up, you might be able to just look in that playlist file (can't help you with that since the real URL isn't above), but I suspect it is encoded in chunks anyway so that won't be useful to other browsers either.  You will have to find the regular MP3 file URL.

Comment: Isn't there a cross-browser solution for audio streaming? So how do online radios work? My goal here is to use Wowza, not a static MP3 file (if that's what you're suggesting...)

Comment: @vitorsdcs Yes, the cross-browser solution is to not use HLS.  It isn't broadly supported at this point, at least not in HTML5 contexts.  JWPlayer has a Flash application that can utilize HLS on all sort of different browsers and devices.  Most internet radio stations work by progressive streaming over HTTP.  SHOUTcast and Icecast are the most common servers.  SHOUTcast isn't recommended as it is the least compatible.  Icecast works well.  I created my own server called AudioPump to get better support for mobile devices.  Does Wowza not have an HTTP progressive mode?

Comment: No, Wowza does not support HTTP progressive download. So it looks like the best option for me will be streaming with Icecast or AudioPump. I'll check that out. Thank you.